# Can we set output of one Datasource Query as input of other Datasource Query in Grafana Mixed Datasource (MS SQL Server)

Tags: grafana

I want to query data by joining two tables in two databases(different datasources in Grafana). I am trying to use Grafana Mixed Datasource for the same. Since I want to query into two different databases (datasources) is it possible to set output of one Datasource Query as input of other Datasource Query to have the joining between to database tables .

Comment: No, what you describe exactly is not possible. But there Transformations *Join by field* and *Merge* that can somewhat join results of two different queries. But this will not provide full analog to DBMS' join, as many-to-one joins aren't supported (and many more).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grafana inner join many to one between 2 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76085792/grafana-inner-join-many-to-one-between-2-database)