# Grafana inner join many to one between 2 database

Tags: grafana

I am using Mixed data sources

I used two postgres databases, created two queries

In transform section, used Join by field => Mode as Inner join. But it is returning only one row instead of many-to-many join

Query1 result

```
user_id, name
1,abc
2,def
```

Query2 result

```
order_id,user_id
1,1
2,1
```

Transform result

```
user_id,order_id,name
1,2,abc
```

Expected transform result

```
user_id,order_id,name
1,1,abc
1,2,abc
```

Is many-to-many or many-to-one join not possible in Grafana?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid this is not supported. My understanding is that field used in join expected to be unique within every query result.

Comment: Can you put this to answer ? i will mark as close

Comment: @markalex - do you know any such open-source tool with this capability except looker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not supported.

My understanding is that field used in join expected to be unique within every query result.

Since joins are more of RDBMS task I would suggest investigate possibility of using Postgres to its fullest. Looking into [dblinks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-function.html), this way you'll get native sql joining capabilities.

Comment: `dblinks` are slow, afaik after reading various questions on SO, articles, etc

Comment: @Yusuf, yes they can be slow. But if you request small amount of data to be processed you shouldn't notice it. Also, I believe it still will be faster that alternative intermediate solutions, like mentioned looker.